# What are server requirements to setup Adobe Streaming video which deliver videos on user computer in f4f file format?

Tags: php, flash, laravel, video-streaming, adobe

Recently I've got requirement to set streaming video. To set this which allow mp4 format to download is easy but my boss want to use Adobe streaming server which allow user to watch videos in many chunk of f4f file format. I am  not aware of server requirement for this and don't know what kind of coding is required for this. Can anyone point me in right direction please? I am all good with PHP, HTML5, jquery and OOP. I am thinking to user laravel framework for this project. What do you say? What about flash player? Any help and comment appreciated.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that both parties need to have the CODEC for the f4f file format on their respective machines.  Computers are what computers are, you just have to tell what it is.  If the very same .mp4 file has had a different file extension put on it, say .txt, then of course the OS won't see it as a media file.  A file format is as a file format does.  Both machines have to have the same software drivers to read and render the files.